# How to use swift protocol implementation in Objective-C?

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am new in iOS. I have a lib that I use in my App both in Swift and Objc files (I have connected my lib correctly including the *-Swift.h file).

So, my lib has such a structure

Factory

```
import Foundation

@objc public class Factory : NSObject{
    @objc public func create() -> ModelProtocol
    {
        return FirstModel()
    }
}
```

Model protocol

```
import Foundation

@objc public protocol ModelProtocol
{
    func foo()
}
```

First Model

```
import Foundation

public class FirstModel : NSObject, ModelProtocol
{
    public func foo() {
        //Do some things here
    }
}
```

when I try to use this factory on the Swift side everything is working properly

```
import Foundation
import Lib

class TestClass {
    
    public init(){}
    
    func boo()
    {
        let factory = Factory()
        let _: ModelProtocol = factory.create()
    }
}
```

but when I try to do the same on the Objc side I got an error

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'ModelProtocol'
```

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Lib-Swift.h"


@implementation ViewController : NSObject

- (void)foo {
    Factory *factory = [Factory new];
    ModelProtocol *protocol = [factory create];
}

@end
```

also I put both these projects (lib & app) on my drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-DMYMhTqTqpgHcp31DNVby7US46OXUYM?usp=sharing

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your only problem is incorrect syntax of protocols in Objective-C. Correctly, a type conforming to protocol would be written this way:

```
id<ModelProtocol> protocol = [factory create];
```